# JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(text)) changes the whole content of this.props - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, visual-studio-code

I am new at using `convertToRaw`, I do not have any idea what exactly it does or what are its features. Searched everywhere. But could not find any appropriate answer.

I have **text** which is saved as **html tags, code** in the database. To display it on the front-end, I am using `.map()`. Displaying does not show any error. I have an edit button when I try to hit edit the **text** which is as *html* in database, it converts to some weird text which I don't know what it is called.

`database data`

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5f589b24c0b387001166e802"},
"textValues":{"text":"<p>Hello World</p>"},
"createdAt":{"$date":"2020-09-09T09:06:44.612Z"},
"updatedAt":{"$date":"2021-09-28T08:00:11.244Z"},
"__v":0}
```

`data which gets changed to some weird text when hit edit button`

```
{"blocks":[{"key":"fbe38","text":"Hello World","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}
```

From `this.props` I pass the data to the function below

`ReactJs function`

```
handleEdit = (textval) => {
        const sampleMarkup = textval.text;
        const contentHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup)
        const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentHTML.contentBlocks, contentHTML.entityMap)
        textval.text= JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(state))
    }
```

`this.props` at the first is normal.

```
createdAt: "2021-09-29T12:57:44.302Z"
textValues:
text: "<p>Hello World</p>"
[[Prototype]]: Object
updatedAt: "2021-09-29T12:57:44.302Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5f589b24c0b387001166e802"
```

But when I pass the `object` to the **function handleEdit**, value of `this.props` changes as below:

```
createdAt: "2021-09-29T12:57:44.302Z"
textValues:
test: "{\"blocks\":[{\"key\":\"d500p\",\"text\":\"Hello World\",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}}],\"entityMap\":{}}"
[[Prototype]]: Object
updatedAt: "2021-09-29T12:57:44.302Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5f589b24c0b387001166e802"
```

Because of this line of code : `textval.text= JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(state))` that weird text above which I mentioned is shown I think. I am not very much sure whther it is because of that or something else.

I have used **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** also to display that *text* on the front end.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textValue.text }} />
```

Using of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` create any problem? If yes is there any other alternative to it?

I do not want that to happen. What do I do? I have absolutely no idea what is going on. I will be happy if anyone would help me with this, and help me resolve my issue. Need help!